# Single Crystalline Thin Films is detect by GIXRD?

Tags: crystallography

I understand epitaxal thin film, have lattice match with substrate.
But what about those films that doesnt match but have only one XRD peak? Is this proof of single crystale thin film?

Comment: *What* is characterized by one peak? Whether the lattices match or not?

Comment: single crystal thin film @andselisk on GIXRD you will observe only one pick, is this correct?

Comment: I'm still not following. What do you mean by "pick"? To select the certain lattice from an array? Or was it a typo and you meant "peak"? This is still the same x-ray diffraction, so there is going to be as many peaks as Bragg's law and systematic extinctions allow. Please refine your question as now it's quite hard to read and to understand what' you are trying to say.

Comment: @andselisk XRD pick, in xrd analysis results

Comment: @andselisk Please sorry, I edited question,  I now realize that it was not clear

Comment: I know what "XRD *peak*" is, but "XRD pick" makes no sense whatsoever (the question says "peak" though, but in the comments you insist on "pick").

Comment: yes, you are right @andselisk english is not my mother tongue, I was referring to how one identify single crystal thin film- is it by occurance of single peak

Comment: English isn't my mother language too, I understand the struggle. I would't rely on a single peak only; this can serve as a lousy proof of crystallinity, but in general I'd do some supplementary tests such as XRF, AFM/SEM, maybe SAXS.